# Build failure in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

i get this error when i make gradle online.

```
Error:Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':ProwessPride_V1.01'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Where **ProwessPride_V1.01** is the jar file which i include in project.

I do Invalidate Caches/Restart in studio. rebuild and clean project also but i can't resolve this error. So please help me how can i solve it.

build.gradle

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.technopits.dcn"
                minSdkVersion 17
                targetSdkVersion 23
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
            compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
            compile project(':ProwessPride_V1.01')
        }
```

buil.gradle project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the **ProwessPride_V1.01** jar file inside your projects libs folder, and remove that line compile project(':ProwessPride_V1.01') from your dependencies and complie, it will work.

Comment: can you tell me step how i put jar inside libs folder

Comment: Drag and Drop or by copy+paste in your explorer/finder

But still you have to add the line:
`compile file('libs/ProwessPride_V1.01')` into your gradle file

Comment: @Erythrozyt **compile file('libs/ProwessPride_V1.01')** line is not required as **compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')** will add the jar files automatically inside lib folder to the gradle.

Comment: Oh yes that is true, overread this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `compile project(':ProwessPride_V1.01')`, gradle is searching for a **project with the same name in the `settings.gradle`**.

Since it is a jar it is wrong.

**Just remove this line.**

```
compile project(':ProwessPride_V1.01')
```

If you adding the jar in the libs folder, this line is enough for you.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Undo any changes you made while adding the library (remove any dependancies or JAR's)
2. Drag n Drop the jar file in libs folder (inside android studio)
3. Clean Build

Comment: "Add as library" is not required. The line compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') is enough